# Export from textarea to CSV file using PHP

Tags: php, html, csv, export

I've been searching on the web and here about exporting data from the textarea to CSV using PHP...

I would like to have the button on my page that will have that CSV file generated and offered for download when it's pressed.

All I could find is exporting from either html table or mysql and I don't need that...

Basically textarea contains some data and once button is pressed I want to be able to download that data as CSV file...

Here is the class that I was trying to customize:

```
<?php 
class textarea_2_csv{

    var $arrLines;
    var $data;
    var $divider;

    function __construct($postedData){

        $this->arrLines = explode("\r\n",$postedData['xls']);
        $this->data = NULL;

    }

    // process the posted data
    function set_data(){

        if(is_array($this->arrLines)){

            if($this->divider == NULL) $this->set_divider(); // default divider setting if no other option is passed

            foreach($this->arrLines as $key=>$line){

                // if more than 1 field
                if(strpos($line, chr(9)) !== FALSE){

                    $arrFields = explode(chr(9),$line);

                    foreach($arrFields as $c=>$val){

                        $this->data .= $val.$this->divider;

                    }

                    $this->data = trim($this->data,$this->divider);
                    $this->data .= "\r\n";

                }
                // if only 1 field
                else{

                    $this->data .= $line."\r\n";

                }

            }       

        }

    }

    // saves the data as file or returns it back
    function save_data($write = false){

        $this->set_data();

        if(!$write == false){

            // write file (.txt if divider is tab)
            ($this->divider == chr(9)) ? $ext = '.txt' : $ext = '.csv';
            if(file_put_contents($write.$ext, $this->data)) echo('<h3>Data saved in file: '.$write.$ext.'</h3>');
            return(NULL);

        }
        else{

            // return de data
            return($this->data);

        }

    }   

    // set the divider as default to a comma
    function set_divider($opt=','){

        $this->divider = $opt;

    }

}
```

Here is the actual page:

```
<?php
require_once('class.textarea2csv.php');
/*
 * 1) initiate the class passing the $_POST data
 * 2) optional: set a different divider than comma (default) with function set_divider(';') or set_divider(chr(9)); options are: ; and tab
 * 3) call the function save_data() without parameter to get the data returned OR call the function save_data('filename') with a parameter to save the data with the given filename
 */

if(isset($_POST['xls']) && trim($_POST['xls']) != ''){

    $csv = new textarea_2_csv($_POST);

    // possibility to set the divider to another format
    // $xls->set_divider(';');
    // $xls->set_divider(chr(9));

    // process data and save it with filename output
    $data = $csv->save_data('output');

}
?>
<html>
    <h2>Example of class "Textarea 2 csv"</h2>
    <p>Copy the the content of an excel sheet, paste it in the textarea and click on "Send".</p>
    <form method="post">
        <p><textarea name="xls" style="width: 800px; height: 400px"></textarea></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Send" /></p>
    </form> 
</html>
```

I cannot customize it as I would like...

Once again, textarea is already filled with some data, and when someone click on the button, he/she should get that data exported as CSV file.

Thank you.

Comment: If textarea filled by data fetched from db, you deo not nned to post texat area content. You can just send data id from db, and get data from database with that id and convert it to csv

Comment: No it's not filled by the data from db...

Comment: If you have unstructured data in textarea how will you construct csv data?

Comment: data is fetched from the web when user search something, then that data is returned in that textarea field, example: 12 march 2010, 13 march 2010, 14 march 2014 etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
if($bdd = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'checkport'))
{
    if(isset($_POST['sub']))
    {
        $drp = "delete from listeadresse";
        mysqli_query($bdd, $drp);
        $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        $file = fOpen($filename, "r");

        $count=0;
        while(($emapdata = fgetcsv($file, 100, ";")) !== FALSE )
        {
```